# Traversing a dictionary recursively

Tags: python, recursion, dictionary, python-2.7

I need to traverse a dictionary recursively and **remember the previous keys**.

Let me explain:

```
dic = {u'resources': {u'info': {u'load': (u'37', u'17')}}, u'peak': {u'load': (u'0', u'1')}}
```

The elements are always a value or a dictionary until it reaches a value.
I want to print the above `dic` like this: (omit the xxx below, it should eventually be a diff of the two values)

```
resources info load 37 17 xxx
resources peak load 0 1 xxx
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
def convertToTable(var):
    if isinstance(var, tuple):
        if len(var) != 2:
            return str(var)

        v1, v2 = var
        try:
            v1 = float(v1)
            v2 = float(v2)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        if type(v1) != type(v2):
            return '\t%s\t%s\n' % (v1, v2)
        elif isinstance(v1, int) or isinstance(v1, float):
            sign = '+' if v2 - v1 > 0 else ''
            return '\t%s\t%s\t%s%s\n' % (v1, v2, sign, v2 - v1)
        elif isinstance(v1, list):
            ret = ''
            for i in range(max(len(v1), len(v2))):
                v1v = v1[i] if i < len(v1) else ''
                v2v = v2[i] if i < len(v2) else ''
                ret += '\t%s, %s\n' % (v1v, v2v)
            return ret
        else:
            return '\t%s\t%s\n' % (v1, v2)
    elif isinstance(var, dict):
        ret = ''
        for key, value in var.iteritems():
            # fix this crap, it's not printing all recursive levels of keys!
            ret += '%s %s' % (key, convertToTable(value))
        return ret
    else:
        return '%s\n' % (var)
```

I don´t know how to pass the previous keys recursively to the function again! Either I get an extra print of keys or nothing! (please do not advice me that I should use `json.dumps` as it does not really do what I need!)
I am hoping someone can check my solution and point out the flaw in it!

Comment: The children can either be type list or dict?

Comment: key `level1` has a value of type dict, but `level2B` and `level3B` have values that are list of dicts. Can/should `level1` be a list containing a single dict?

Comment: @fabian, sorry I messed up the example. the children are always an element or a tuple

Comment: @theAlse what's an element? Can you update your post?

Comment: sorry guys, I messed up the example. please see the updated one!

Comment: @theAlse what if you had a second entry below peak?

Comment: @fabian, then it would be yet another dict inside. like `dic = {u'resources': {u'info': {u'load': (u'37', u'17')}}, u'peak': {u'xxx': {u'yyy': (u'37', u'17')}}}`

Comment: @theAlse so this cannot happen? `'peak': {'load': ['0', '1'], 'unload': ['2', '3']}, 'resources': {'info': {'load': ['37', '17']}}}`

Comment: @Fabian, sure that can happen! but no lists, only tuples. elements are either dict or tuples like this: `dic = {'peak': {'load': ('0', '1'), 'unload': ('2', '3')}, 'resources': {'info': {'load': ('37', '17')}}}`

Comment: I notice that your post does not have a question. **What is your question?**

Comment: Also, it appears that your sample input and sample output don't match. Did you intend for `'peak'` to be a top-level key, or a 2nd-level key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your code, but this might do what you want:

```
def iteritems_recursive(d):
  for k,v in d.iteritems():
    if isinstance(v, dict):
      for k1,v1 in iteritems_recursive(v):
        yield (k,)+k1, v1
    else:
      yield (k,),v

dic = {u'resources': {u'info': {u'load': (u'37', u'17')}, u'peak': {u'load': (u'0', u'1')}}}

for p,v in iteritems_recursive(dic):
  print p, "->", v
```

`iteritems_recursive` iterates over the passed-in dictionary, and returns a a `(path, value)` tuple. The `path` is itself a tuple which describes the keys that reach that item.

The above code prints:

```
(u'resources', u'info', u'load') -> (u'37', u'17')
(u'resources', u'peak', u'load') -> (u'0', u'1')
```

If you want to print the table pretty, replace the for loop above with this:

```
for p,v in iteritems_recursive(dic):
  diff = float(v[0]) - float(v[1])
  p = ''.join('{:10}'.format(w) for w in p)
  v = ''.join('{:5}'.format(f) for f in v)
  print p, v, diff
```

Which prints:

```
resources info      load       37   17    20.0
resources peak      load       0    1     -1.0
```

Comment: I was hoping someone could point out the flaw in my solution. I don´t know how I would have to change this code to get a diff of the value.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question, because *you didn't ask one*. You might want to edit your post and include a specific question.

Comment: What is a 'diff of the value'? What, precisely, do you want the output to look like, given your sample input?

Comment: I meant the difference between the two provided value for each item, but that is easy to get from your code too

Comment: I am accepting your solution as it is the most simple and easy to understand

Comment: is there a way to modify the function to handle this case. `dic = {u'resources': {u'info': {u'load': (u'37', u'17')}, u'peak': {u'load': (u'0', u'1')}}, u'statistics': (None, OrderedDict([(u'depth', u'0'), (u'depth2', u'0'), (u'depth3', u'0')]))}` (when an element is a dict it should be appended to the original Dict)

Answer (score 2):

```
def convertToTable(inp, history=[]):
    for key, value in inp.iteritems():
        history.append(key)
        if type(value) == dict:
            convertToTable(value, history)
        else:
            print '{} {} {}'.format(' -> '.join(history), value[0], value[1])
        history.pop()

dic = {'peak': {'load': ('0', '1'), 'unload': ('2', '3')}, 'resources': {'info': {'loadxx': ('37', '17')}}}
convertToTable(dic)

# peak -> load 0 1
# peak -> unload 2 3
# resources -> info -> loadxx 37 17
```

Answer (score 2):

I have two solutions, the first carries the names of all the keys down the levels and prints them at the bottom before returning back up the stack.

The second prints them on the way down thus avoiding having to 'remember' the levels

```
import sys

dic = {u'resources':
            {u'info':
                {u'load': (u'37', u'17')}
            },
       u'peak':
            {u'load': (u'0', u'1')}
      }


def racecar(goomba, levels=None):
    if levels == None:
        levels = []
    for key in goomba:
        if type(goomba[key]) is dict:
            levels.append(key)
            levels = racecar(goomba[key], levels)
        else:
            levels.append(key)
            for name in levels:
                sys.stdout.write(name + ' ')
            for val in goomba[key]:
                sys.stdout.write(val + ' ')
            sys.stdout.write('xxx\n')
            return []


def racecar2(goomba):
    for key in goomba:
        sys.stdout.write(key + ' ')
        if type(goomba[key]) is dict:
            racecar(goomba[key])
        else:
            for val in goomba[key]:
                sys.stdout.write(val + ' ')
            sys.stdout.write('xxx\n')

racecar(dic)
racecar2(dic)
```

returns:

```
peak load 0 1 xxx
resources info load 37 17 xxx
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, both your solutions are incorrect! almost in the same way mine is incorrect. have you ran them and checked the print, it does not even print all the elements!

Comment: the output specified in your question doesn't seem to reflect the input provided. What output are you expecting?

Comment: oops I missed the `load` element, fixed now